# Where filter not working in jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am struggling to get a where filer working in jekyll.

In my collection help I have a front matter array in each post of:

`colleague_role:
- All colleagues`

Or

`colleague_role:
- Cleaner`

Depending on the job type. When looping through these I am trying to do:

```
{% for post in site.help | where:"colleague_role","All colleagues" %}
<li><a href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ post.title }} {{ post.colleague_role }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

However the where filter is ignored and I get all posts... Note {{ post.colleague_role }} in the anchor is working and outputting the job role.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Solved with:

```
{% for post in site.help %}
{% if post.colleague_role contains "All colleagues" %}
    <li><a href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Using the `relative_url` filter is more robust than `prepend: site.baseurl`: `<li><a href="{{ post.url | relative_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>`